# Fsolve equivalent in C++

Tags: c++, matlab, optimization, constraints

I am trying to replicate Matlab's Fsolve as my project is in C++ solving an implicit RK4 scheme. I am using the NLopt library using the NLOPT_LD_MMA algorithm. I have run the required section in matlab and it is considerably faster. I was wondering whether anyone had any ideas of a better Fsolve equivalent in C++? Another reason is that I would like f1 and f2 to both tend to zero and it seems suboptimal to calculate the L2 norm to include both of them as NLopt seems to only allow a scalar return value from the objective function. Does anyone have any ideas of an alternative library or perhaps using a different algorithm/constraints to more closely replicate the default fsolve.

Would it be better (faster) perhaps to call the python scipy.minimise.fsolve from C++?

````
double implicitRK4(double time, double V, double dt, double I, double O, double C, double R){

    const int number_of_parameters = 2;
    double lb[number_of_parameters];
    double ub[number_of_parameters];
    lb[0] = -999; // k1 lb
    lb[1] = -999;//  k2 lb

    ub[0] = 999; // k1 ub
    ub[1] = 999; // k2 ub

    double k [number_of_parameters];
    k[0] = 0.01;
    k[1] = 0.01;
    kOptData addData(time,V,dt,I,O,C,R);

    nlopt_opt opt; //NLOPT_LN_MMA NLOPT_LN_COBYLA
    opt = nlopt_create(NLOPT_LD_MMA, number_of_parameters);

    nlopt_set_lower_bounds(opt, lb);
    nlopt_set_upper_bounds(opt, ub);
    nlopt_result nlopt_remove_inequality_constraints(nlopt_opt opt);

//    nlopt_result nlopt_remove_equality_constraints(nlopt_opt opt);

    nlopt_set_min_objective(opt,solveKs,&addData);
    double minf;
    if (nlopt_optimize(opt, k, &minf) < 0) {
        printf("nlopt failed!\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("found minimum at f(%g,%g,%g) = %0.10g\n", k[0],k[1],minf);
    }

    nlopt_destroy(opt);

    return  V + (1/2)*dt*k[0] + (1/2)*dt*k[1];```
````

```
double solveKs(unsigned n, const double *x, double *grad, void *my_func_data){

    kOptData *unpackdata = (kOptData*) my_func_data;
    double t1,y1,t2,y2;
    double f1,f2;
    t1 = unpackdata->time + ((1/2)-(1/6)*sqrt(3));
    y1 = unpackdata->V + (1/4)*unpackdata->dt*x[0] + ((1/4)-(1/6)*sqrt(3))*unpackdata->dt*x[1];

    t2 = unpackdata->time + ((1/2)+(1/6)*sqrt(3));
    y2 = unpackdata->V + ((1/4)+(1/6)*sqrt(3))*unpackdata->dt*x[0] + (1/4)*unpackdata->dt*x[1];

    f1 = x[0] - stateDeriv_implicit(t1,y1,unpackdata->dt,unpackdata->I,unpackdata->O,unpackdata->C,unpackdata->R);
    f2 =  x[1] - stateDeriv_implicit(t2,y2,unpackdata->dt,unpackdata->I,unpackdata->O,unpackdata->C,unpackdata->R);

    return sqrt(pow(f1,2) + pow(f2,2));
```

My matlab version below seems to be a lot simpler but I would prefer the whole code in c++!

```
k1 = 0.01;
k2 = 0.01;
x0 = [k1,k2];
fun = @(x)solveKs(x,t,z,h,I,OCV1,Cap,Rct,static);
options = optimoptions('fsolve','Display','none');
k = fsolve(fun,x0,options);
% Calculate the next state vector from the previous one using RungeKutta
% update equation
znext = z + (1/2)*h*k(1) + (1/2)*h*k(2);``
```

```
function [F] = solveKs(x,t,z,h,I,O,C,R,static)

t1 = t + ((1/2)-(1/6)*sqrt(3));
y1 = z + (1/4)*h*x(1) + ((1/4)-(1/6)*sqrt(3))*h *x(2);

t2 = t + ((1/2)+(1/6)*sqrt(3));
y2 = z + ((1/4)+(1/6)*sqrt(3))*h*x(1) + (1/4)*h*x(2);

F(1) = x(1) - stateDeriv_implicit(t1,y1,h,I,O,C,R,static);
F(2) =  x(2) - stateDeriv_implicit(t2,y2,h,I,O,C,R,static);
end
```

Comment: The obvious first question is; did you compile your program with compiler optimizations enabled or are you testing a default unoptimized, slow, debug build? Enabling compiler optimizations can make orders of magnitude differences to performance.

Comment: @JesperJuhl just a slow debug build. I wasn't aware it made that much of a significant difference. I apologise if I am being naive. I will try it.

Comment: It doesn't *always* make huge differences - it depends on your code, but it *can* easily make 10x or 100x differences for the right code. For other code you may just see trivial improvements. But you should *always* measure performance with optimized builds.

Comment: C++ very much relies on an *optimizing* compiler to be fast. It has nice abstractions that are expensive on the surface but are designed to collapse completely under optimization, etc. It is very much designed to be compiled with an optimizing compiler to achieve speed. A debug / unoptimized build is not going to be fast. It's the default of most compilers simply because it's easier to debug.

Comment: Thanks very much for this. I am using g++ so is -03 the best I can do?

Comment: @MikeyPatterson `(1/4)` -- This and anything that looks like this in your code is an int divided by int, yielding an int.  Thus the value here is `0`, not `0.25`.  The numerator and/or denominator must be a floating point value to have a floating point result.  For example `(1.0 / 4)`.  Once you make those changes, rerun your code.

Comment: @MikeyPatterson There's no definitive answer. Different compilers generate different code on different platforms. And with different optimization options, different programs perform differently. And some options may do well for some programs and poorly for others. It's not Simple. As a general rule, `-O2` for gcc will do pretty good. But the real answer is; "it's complicated".

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie oh thanks for noticing! Just copied it straight over without thinking.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @MikeyPatterson You need to test and benchmark different stuff to see what works best for *your* application. There's no magic "best" option, for everything.

Comment: @MikeyPatterson But I'm currious; did enabling *some* sort of compiler optimization help your program or not?

Comment: @JesperJuhl I haven't tried as im struggling with the constraints, I will let you know when I do!